# Not work: Android Studio 3.2 Canary11 + 3.2.0-alpha11 for kapt with com.android.databinding

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding, gradle-plugin

Android Studio 3.2 Canary11

Gradle Tool 3.2.0-alpha11

com.android.databinding of kapt doesn't work with 3.2.0-alpha11, can not build / run apk.

Meanwhile, it works max with 3.2.0-alpha10

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDevDebugKotlin'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kapt'.
>   Could not find com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha11.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            file:/Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            file:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            file:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            file:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            file:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            file:/Users/xxx/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.pom
>            https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/databinding/compiler/3.2.0-alpha11/compiler-3.2.0-alpha11.jar
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   ```

[issues](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78206426)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if I removed the dependency of databinding.
case closed

no more need to link `com.android.databinding:compiler`, since a version of android gradle plugin, it would be imported automatically.

Comment: Is this true? Because if I don't add the dependency, it doesn't generate the `BR` class for binding adapters.

Answer (score 12):

Remove this line

```
kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha10'
```