# Android Studio 3.2 stable, Could not find databinding-compiler-common.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

I just updated to Android Studio 3.2 stable, but I get this error when I'm trying to sync my old projects or new ones with gradle:

> Could not find databinding-compiler-common.jar
>   (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:3.2.0). Searched in
>   the following locations:
>       https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/3.2.0/databinding-compiler-common-3.2.0.jar

How can I fix this?

**Update:** I looked around for the dependency and it wasn't there to delete, I invalidated cache, I did a fresh reinstall and nothing worked so I went back to 3.1. This happens in windows but there's no problem in Linux with same projects.

Comment: same problem since update to 3.2, please notify when find answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to version 3.2.1 fixed the problem. It must have been a bug for some people!

Answer (score 0):

no more need of this dependency like answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907345/not-work-android-studio-3-2-canary11-3-2-0-alpha11-for-kapt-with-com-android/49916054#49916054)

When Android Studio gives you errors after that, try to Rebuild or maybe use > File > Invalidate Cache & Restart.

Comment: Should've updated the question, I already tried that...I looked around in the dependency and it wasn't there to delete, I invalidated cache, I did a fresh reinstall and nothing worked so I went back to 3.1. This happens in windows but there's no problem in Linux with same project.

Comment: I work on Windows too and had other errors on databinding, but there were also other errors not linked to databinding. After solving seconds errors, build was successful

Comment: I'm not getting any other errors in neither windows nor Linux

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine after I removed the following line for annotation processor from app's build.gradle following Android Studio 3.2 update: `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:${dataBindingVersion}"`

Comment: As I mentioned, there was nothing in the dependencies that included "databinding"!

Comment: This won't work because com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2+ doesn't exist... https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I already had this problem with the Android Studio version 4

I **reinstalled** Android Studio, Then it was fixed :)